# doctrine2 entity number in month generation

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity, symfony4

I've got Invoice entity, in which I'd like to generate subsequent numbers within a given month.
Entity code:

```
/**
 * Class Invoice
 * @package App\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Invoice
{
(...)
   /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $year;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $month;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="App\Helper\InvoiceNumberGenerator")
     */
    private $counter;
(...)
    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function numberGenerator()
    {
        if ($this->getYear() === null) {
            $this->setYear(date('Y'));
            $this->setMonth(date('m'));
        }
    }
```

And App\Helper\InvoiceNumberGenerator code is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Helper;


use App\Entity\Invoice;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Id\AbstractIdGenerator;
use Exception;

class InvoiceNumberGenerator extends AbstractIdGenerator
{

    /**
     * Generates an invoice number
     *
     * @param EntityManager $em
     * @param Invoice $entity
     * @return mixed
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function generate(EntityManager $em, $entity)
    {
        if (!$entity instanceof Invoice) {
            throw new Exception('Generator służy tylko do generowania numerów faktur.');
        }
        /** @var ObjectRepository | EntityRepository $invoiceRepository */
        $invoiceRepository = $em->getRepository(Invoice::class);

        /** @var Invoice $lastInvoice */
        $lastInvoice = $invoiceRepository->findOneBy(
            array(
                'year' => $entity->getYear(),
                'month' => $entity->getMonth()
            ),
            array(
                'counter' => 'desc'
            )
        );

        if (empty($lastInvoice)) {
            return 1;
        }

        return $lastInvoice->getCounter() + 1;
    }
}
```

When I dump `$lastInvoice`, it shows:

```
Invoice {#5522 ▼
  -id: 1
  -generated: false
  -fileName: "example"
  -year: 2019
  -month: 11
  -counter: 1
  -name: "AG"
  -company: "Gall"
  -address: "Street 1"
  -address2: "Gliwice"
  -nip: "6314567890"
  -reservation: Reservation {#5855 ▶}
  -date: null
}
```

So it looks like the generator gets to selecting last one correctly, but nevertheless I got error when trying to create new Invoice:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'counter'
>   cannot be null

Any advise on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `@CustomIdGenerator` annotation is only called when the column is also marked with `@Id`. From the [docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#customidgenerator):

> This annotations allows you to specify a user-provided class to generate identifiers. This annotation only works when both @Id and @GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM") are specified.

Ids are always a special kind of thing and thus must sometimes be perfect before inserting. To solve your problem - because the counter is not an id column -, you could use [lifecycle events](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) instead (prePersist, probably) and use the [event's entity manager](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#listening-and-subscribing-to-lifecycle-events) in an event listener/subscriber to run your query.

Comment: I didn't catch that it only applies to @Id field. You're right I should use Event Subscriber on prePersist, but in the meantime I figured out I need to generate the number only after generated is set to true so rebuilt all of that completely. Thank you thou.